# Error when trying to setup integration between slack and salesforce

Tags: slack

I'm trying to setup slack app step 5 "Automation Configuration". When I click on New Message Destination button it throws an error:

> Attempt to de-reference a null object.
>
> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
> failed: slackv2:messageDestinationForm$controller$cancelClick [Cannot
> read property 'clear' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
> {slackv2:messageDestinationForm$controller$cancelClick}

My custom domain is enabled for my sandbox and site added in remote site settings.

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details on the reference "slack app step 5 Automation Configuration" so I can try to reproduce this behavior to suggest better?

Comment: Sure, trying to Create Custom Message Destinations as described in this module
 https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/integrate-salesforce-with-slack/automate-slack-messages

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with 1.6 version installed. Version upgrade didn't help. I've uninstalled and installed the latest version and it helped.